# DataContract deserializer with Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

If i have an xml like:

```
<Foo>
<Bar>
    <A>aaaa</A>
    <B>bbb</B>
</Bar>
<C>ccc</C></Foo>
```

Can I deserialize it into a Foo class with a dictionary structure and a string property like following  using the same DataContract Deserializer? With A and B as the keys and the "aaaa" and "bbb" as the Values in the dictionary?

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{

  [DataMember]
  public Dictionary<string, string> Bar
  { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string C { get; set; }
}
```

I know there is an example using CollectionDataContract on MSDN site but it only uses the A as the key and B as the value.

Comment: A Dictionary needs keys, if you only want A and B to be values, then what are your keys going to be? If you don't want keys use List instead.

Comment: No I want A and B to be keys and what inside to be the values. I am saying there is an example of using A as the key and B as the value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this automatically. If you want a dictionary, you should use LINQ to XML, and create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing you'll be able to get to is something like this

```
<UserQuery.Foo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Bar>
       <Barentry>
          <A>aaa</A>
          <B>bbb</B>
       </Barentry>
    </Bar>
<C i:nil="true"/>
</UserQuery.Foo>
```

using this code to test:

```
void Main()
{

var B=new Bar();
B.Add("aaa","bbb");
var tFoo=new Foo(){Bar=B};
DataContractSerializer ser=new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo));
ToXml<Foo>(tFoo).Dump();

}


        public static string ToXml<T>(T obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
            String text;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
                byte[] data = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                Array.Copy(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), data, data.Length);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            }
            return text;
        }



[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class Foo
{

  [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
  public Bar Bar
  { get; set; }

  [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
  public string C { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract
    (ItemName="Barentry",
    KeyName = "A", 
    ValueName = "B")]
public class Bar:Dictionary<string,string>{
}
```